# Jenkins pod failing to initialize

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I am having a major problem with Jenkins pod not being able to start.

This is how my kubernetes deployment looks like

https://justpaste.it/8ff07

This is the log that I am getting when I investigate the logs https://justpaste.it/64vpb

I am using this command to investigate the logs `kubectl logs jenkins-df87c46d5-52dtt -c copy-default-config -n infrastructure`

My pod looks like this:
`infrastructure jenkins-5589d85c76-9tvj5 0/1 Init:0/1  3  30m`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you behind proxy/firewall? Can you try to add `empty plugin` list and see if that helps? What is your pod status? is it `Init:CrashLoopBackOff` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to "being behind proxy" as described here in this [article](https://www.devtech101.com/2019/06/18/installing-jenkins-on-your-kubernets-cluster-by-using-helm-charts/).

Jenkins by default will try to install list of plugins which if it fails/timeout will cause the install to not complete and fail.

Two possible solutions for this are:

- Install Jenkins with empty plugin list. You do so by adding a line
  installPlugins: to your helm/jenkins-values.yml with no entry

- Add your proxy to the helm/jenkins-values.yml